# Getting After waiting for 10s, the test coroutine is not completing after trying to run test

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, junit, mockito

I'm Trying to learn JUnit and Mockito. I was trying to test some response codes, and I've faced error:

```
    After waiting for 10s, the test coroutine is not completing
kotlinx.coroutines.test.UncompletedCoroutinesError: After waiting for 10s, the test coroutine is not completing
    at app//kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTest$2$1$2$1.invoke(TestBuilders.kt:349)
    at app//kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTest$2$1$2$1.invoke(TestBuilders.kt:333)
    at app//kotlinx.coroutines.InvokeOnCancelling.invoke(JobSupport.kt:1430)
    at app//kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.notifyCancelling(JobSupport.kt:1474)
    at app//kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.tryMakeCancelling(JobSupport.kt:798)
    at app//kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.makeCancelling(JobSupport.kt:758)
    at app//kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.cancelImpl$kotlinx_coroutines_core(JobSupport.kt:674)
    at app//kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.cancelCoroutine(JobSupport.kt:661)
    at app//kotlinx.coroutines.TimeoutCoroutine.run(Timeout.kt:159)
    at app//kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase$DelayedRunnableTask.run(EventLoop.common.kt:501)
    at app//kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:280)
    at app//kotlinx.coroutines.DefaultExecutor.run(DefaultExecutor.kt:108)
    at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Main coroutine rule:

```
    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class MainCoroutineRule(
    val testDispatcher: TestDispatcher = UnconfinedTestDispatcher()
) : TestWatcher() {

    override fun starting(description: Description) {
        Dispatchers.setMain(testDispatcher)
    }

    override fun finished(description: Description) {
        Dispatchers.resetMain()
    }
}
```

Api test class

```
    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class ApiServicesTest {
    @get:Rule
    val mockitoRule: MockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule()

    @get:Rule
    val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    private lateinit var mockWebServer: MockWebServer
    private lateinit var apiServices: ApiServices

    @Before
    fun setup() {

        mockWebServer = MockWebServer()
        apiServices = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(mockWebServer.url("/"))
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create()
    }

    @After
    fun teardown() {
        mockWebServer.shutdown()
    }

    @Test
    fun `test1`() =
        runTest {
            mockWebServer.enqueue(
                MockResponse()
                    .setResponseCode(200)
                    .setBody("{}")
            )

            val response = apiServices.getLatestRates("", "")
            val body = response.body()
            assertThat(body).isNotNull()
        }


    @Test
    fun `t2`() = runTest {
            mockWebServer.enqueue(MockResponse()
                .setResponseCode(104)
                .setBody("{}")
            )
            val apiCall = apiServices.getLatestRates("", "")
            assertThat(apiCall.code()).isEqualTo(104)
        }
    }
```

I've tried to switch from `UnconfinedTestDispatcher` to the standard one, but it haven't solve the problem. The first test runs just fine.

Also, I'd like to ask, if tests like the ones I've provided, are enough for testing an api call endpoints interface? I'm not sure what I can add here (besides more tests). They seem kinda short.

@Edit
I've changed the response code, to the 200/404. Both were working. Does calling codes <200 are forbidden, or something?